# Given that $\sin\theta = 4\sin(\theta - 60°)$, show that $2\sqrt{3}\cos(\theta) = \sin(\theta) $

Tags: trigonometry

The answer I get when I try to simplify the first equation gives me $2\sin\theta - 2\sqrt{3}\cos\theta,$ which clearly is not the same as $2\sqrt{3}\cos\theta$.

Or am I missing something obvious?

I've attached a screenshot of the question directly from the book.

Thanks in advance.
[image: question]

Comment: for this $\theta$, they are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $\sin\theta=4\sin(\theta-60^o)=2\sin\theta-2\sqrt3\cos\theta$.

Now subtract $\sin\theta$ from both sides:

$0=\sin\theta-2\sqrt3\cos\theta,$

or $2\sqrt3\cos\theta=\sin\theta$.

Answer (score 2):

Given: $\sin \theta = 4\sin(\theta - 60^{\circ})$

Expand right hand side using angle sum (difference) identity:

$\sin \theta = 4(\sin\theta\cos 60^{\circ} - \cos\theta\sin 60^{\circ}) $

Note $\cos 60^{\circ} = \frac 12, \sin 60^{\circ} = \frac {\sqrt 3}2$

Simplifying the above:

$\sin \theta = 2\sin\theta - 2\sqrt 3{\cos\theta} $

Rearrange, simplify:

$2\sqrt 3{\cos\theta} = \sin\theta$ as required.

To finish up the solution, you can divide both sides by $\cos\theta$ after verifying that no solution of $\cos\theta = 0$ solves the equation (it doesn't, so the division is permitted).

Then solve $\tan\theta = 2\sqrt 3$ using a calculator. Within the stipulated range, the value you get by taking the inverse sine on your calculator will be the only valid solution (tangent is non-negative only in the first and third quadrants, only the first quadrant applies in this range).